# cannot connect loopback with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, loopbackjs, strongloop

i'm trying to execute the commande "slc run" to access to API loopback but ther's a problem with mongodb even if i run mongod it display this error :

```
MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\abdessamad\ingeweb_workspace\roll-lo
opback\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
    at C:\Users\abdessamad\ingeweb_workspace\roll-loopback\node_modules\mongodb-
core\lib\connection\pool.js:483:72
    at authenticateStragglers (C:\Users\abdessamad\ingeweb_workspace\roll-loopba
ck\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:429:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (C:\Users\abdessamad\ingeweb_workspace\roll-loo
pback\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:463:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\abdessamad\ingeweb_workspace\roll-loopback\n
ode_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:319:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
```

Comment: Provide more details, e.g. datasources description as well as real mongodb server configuration.

Comment: Looks your database is not properly configured.

Comment: thanks to you, i didn't have database configured properly, the error was in the username, thanks.